# Selecting multiple XML node attributes with LINQ.. why is everything after the first attribute null?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have the following sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<queryableData>
  <table displayName="Shipments" dbName="Quotes">
    <foreignKey column="CustomerId" references="CustomerRegistration"/>
    <foreignKey column="QuoteStatusId" references="QuoteStatus"/>
    <fields>
      <field displayName="Quote Charge" dbColumn="QuoteCharge" type="Number"/>
      <field displayName="Total Weight" dbColumn="TotalWeight" type="Number"/>
    </fields>
  </table>
</queryableData>
```

and I'm trying to create an anonymous object with the contents of the `field` node.  Here is my LINQ code:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load("queryable.xml");
var elem = from el in root.Elements("table")
select new
{
    DisplayName = el.Attribute("displayName").Value,
    Column = el.Attribute("dbColumn").Value,
    DataType = el.Attribute("type").Value
};
```

If I only specify the "DisplayName" attribute, it works fine.  The other two are always null, and therefore trying to read the Value property is throwing a NullReferenceException.

What's the correct way to grab all of the three attributes that I need from the element?  I think I am on the right track but missing something with the query (it seems to me that `el` isn't the entire element)

EDIT:  Nevermind, I'm an idiot.  I'm looking at one element and querying for the other!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sample document the sole `table` element has two attributes named `displayName` and `dbName`, I don't see any `dbColumn` or `type` attribute on the `table` element. If you want to access the `field` elements then use `root.Descendants("field")` instead of `root.Element("table")`.